# Failed to update database <db name> because the database is read-only

Tags: azure-sql-database

We subscribe to Windows Azure for our Database. Currently, I copied the DB of our Production instance into our Development instance and it was successfully done. All tables, including data are completely copied. Right now I am trying to run delete statement to remove unnecessary data but I was not able to proceed and this is the error message I am getting in SQL Server Management Studio.

"Failed to update database  because the database is read-only. Please contact your Azure service owner. There may be billing related issues with your Azure account."

I asked my team mate to understand where could I find the Database Logs but they told me that we don't have access on database application folder.

Can someone advise how should I proceed?

By the way, we have 5 DBs in 1 server and I was able to made modification (run update/delete statement) to those 4 DBs except this one. Same user and permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your database has reached its max size.

You can use the `Alter Database` syntax to bump up the max size.

Before doing so make sure you know how that will [affect your billing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee621788.aspx).